# how to base64-decode a file line by line

Tags: vim

I have a file which is encoded by base64:

```
5byg5bCP5piO
c2FyYWg=
5p2O56OK
```

I want to decode it line by line:

```
:%!base64 -d
```

But I get everything in one line:

```
张小明sarah李磊
```

What I want is:

```
张小明
sarah
李磊
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution is the following, which works nicely for me.

```
%g/^/.!base64 -d
```

Comment: `:g/./.!base64 -d`

Comment: vimgolfist? ;-) Yeah, the `%` is in case of `:g` redundant. Also the `.` regexp makes sense - no use to try to decode empty lines.

Answer (score 4):

```
:%normal !!base64 -d^M
```

---

```
:{range}norm[al][!] {commands}                          *:normal-range*
                        Execute Normal mode commands {commands} for each line
                        in the {range}.  Before executing the {commands}, the
                        cursor is positioned in the first column of the range,
                        for each line.  Otherwise it's the same as the
                        ":normal" command without a range.
                        {not in Vi}
                        Not available when |+ex_extra| feature was disabled at
                        compile time.
```

---

Yet another way:

```
sed 's/$/Cg==/' | base64 -d
```

Comment: On mac os, I had to use -D option. -d didn't work.